# Is this fact true about anagrammatical substrings?

Tags: c#, string, algorithm, optimization, time-complexity

I'm trying to write an algorithm that finds the number of anagrammatical substrings of a string. For instance, the string `"abba"` has 4:

(1) `"a"`, `"a"`

(2) `"b"`, `"b"`

(3) `"ab"`, `"ba"`

(4) `"abb"`, `"bba"`

A fact I'm trying to use to optimize is

> If a string has no anagrammatical pairs of substrings of length k,
>   then it has no anagrammatical pairs of substrings of length k+1

Can you confirm whether that's true or not?

Because my algorithm

```
static int NumAnagrammaticalPairs(string str)
{
    int count = 0; // count of anagrammatical pairs found
    int n = str.Length / 2; // OPTIMIZATION: only need to look through the substrings of half the size or less
    for(int k = 1; k <= n; ++k) 
    {
        // get all substrings of length k
        var subsk = GetSubstrings(str,k).ToList();

        // count the number of anagrammatical pairs
        var indices = Enumerable.Range(0, subsk.Count);
        int anapairs = (from i in indices
                        from j in indices
                        where i < j && IsAnagrammaticalPair(subsk[i], subsk[j])
                        select 1).Count();

        // OPTIMIZATION: if didn't find any anagrammatical pairs in the substrings of length k, 
        // there are no anagrammatical pairs in the substrings of length k+1, so we can exit
        // the loop early
        if(anapairs == 0)
            break;
        else
            count += anapairs;
    }
    return count;       
}
```

is getting results *sliggggtttthhhhly* off (usually off by 1) the actual results in the test cases.

Comment: Why are you stopping at half the size of the string?  Your 4th example ("abb" and "bba") shows pairs of length 3 in a string of length 4 where as your algorithm stops looking at length 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not the case - `abcd` and `cdab` are anagrams of length 4 but you can't find length 3 anagram substrings. Concretely, `abcdab` will not work, since it contains both `abcd` and `cdab`, but no 3 anagrams (from `abc`, `bcd`, `cda`, `dab`).